# How to verify the split history of SPB?

Tags: equities, split

https://www.splithistory.com/spb/

I see a 162 for 1000 reverse split of SPB on 07/16/2018 as shown above.

But the stock open price on 07/16/2018 is 82.70, the stock close price on 07/13/2018 is 82.72.

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPB/history

This does not seem to be correct as a split of 1:8 surely should affect the stock price.

However, yahoo finance also shows a split of 162:1000.

So I am not sure whether there is indeed a split but somehow the price is not affected.

Could anybody let me know how to verify whether there is this split for SPB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what Yahoo states in their footnotes:
[image: Yahoo footnote regarding adjustments]

the OHL data has also been adjusted.

In this case, Hargbinger Group (HRG) initiated a reverse merger with Spectrum Brands Holdings, on the basis of 0.16125 HRG for the merged entity Spectrum Brands Holdings.  So the accurate reverse split ratio is actually 16125:100000.

Many providers round these ratios - it's probably doesn't make a material difference though.

To verify the full details you should review the SEC filings. You can go here:
https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html
then search for Spectrum Brands Holdings
and scroll down until you see the 8-K report dated 2018-07-13:
[image: 8K report Spectrum Brands Holdings]

which points you to this:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0000109177/000119312518217953/d497639d8k.htm

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the price history on Yahoo finance:

[image]

Observe the footnotes:

> *Close price adjusted for splits.**Adjusted close price adjusted for splits and dividend and/or capital gain distributions.

Yahoo help: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28256.html